# Is there any possibility that a gas planet turns into a star

Tags: the-sun, jupiter, gas-giants, saturn, hydrogen

Since the sun is made of one of elements hydrogen 
Why Saturn and jupiter doesnt turn into a star since they have a elements of hydrogen ?

Comment: They are way too small. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10331/16685

Comment: You need 13 Jupiter masses to only start fusing Deuterium, and 82 to start fusing hydrogen, so no.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Do you want to put that into a short answer?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I guess I could, but I would just be duplicating https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33164/if-jupiter-were-to-absorb-all-other-planets-in-the-solar-system-would-it-reach/33165#33165

Comment: The claimed duplicate isn't a duplicate. However, this probably is https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16403/could-the-earth-become-a-star-if-more-mass-was-added

Comment: Stars have fusion. Protons aren't very glad to fuse - first, they distract each other quite strongly, and second, the resulting di-proton wouldn't be stable. The only way to fuse protons is that "somehow" one of them "decays" to a neutron, and then the neutron and the proton fuses already easily. It requires a tremendous pressure and temperature, large planets simply don't have enough. However, this fusion produces a deuterium nucleus, and these fuse already much easier. Thus, a big deuterium cloud could become a star already from much smaller mass, but it doesn't exist.